# How to get authenticated user information from Next.js API request

Tags: next.js, supabase

I'm implementing a project with Supabase and Next.js where I would like to have the authenticated client make an API request to an endpoint. At that endpoint, I'd like to be able to get the user from the database.

My understanding is that on the client, I can call

```
supabase.auth.session().access_token
```

to get the JWT. I could include that token in my `/api/` request, but how would I look up the user in the server-side function?

I tried using the service key and calling

```
supabase.auth.api.getUser('that token that I sent from the client')
```

but that doesn't seem to be the appropriate use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(I don't want to use the client-side query with row-level security because I want to make external API calls from the server.)

Comment: _"that doesn't seem to be the appropriate use"_ - why doesn't that seem the appropriate use? That's exactly how you should do it. Have a look through supabase's official example: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/tree/master/examples/nextjs-with-supabase-auth.